# Intuitive explanation why in some contexts logarithm shifted by Euler-Mascheroni constant is more natural

Tags: integration, limits, special-functions

Natural logarithm is defined as inverse function to exponent. This way defined it has the value of $0$ in $x=1$.

But if we define [natural integral](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179202/prove-that-these-two-definitions-of-natural-integration-constant-coincide-when) the following way

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{- i \omega x}}{\omega} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt \, d\omega$$

we [will find](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=I%20InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[1%2Ft%2C%20t%2C%20w]%2Fw%2C%20w%2C%20x]) that natural integral of $1/x$ is $\ln|x|+\gamma$.

Indeed, the natural differintegral of the function will be

$$D^s [1/x]=\frac{(-1)^s \Gamma(s+1)}{x^{s+1}}$$

This function diverges at $s=-1$, but its mean value at $s=-1$ in limit is

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac12 \left( \frac{-\Gamma(h)}{x^{h}}+\frac{-\Gamma(-h)}{x^{-h}}\right)=\ln|x|+\gamma$$

Now if we consider natural antidifference of $1/x$, we get the following formula for discrete differintegral:

$$\Delta ^{s}[1/x]=\frac{(-1)^s \Gamma (s+1) \Gamma (x)}{(s+x)!}$$

which also diverges at $s=-1$ but its main value will be

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac12\left(-\frac{\Gamma (x) \Gamma (-h+s+1)}{(-h+s+x)!}-\frac{\Gamma (x) \Gamma (h+s+1)}{(h+s+x)!}\right)=\psi(x)+\gamma$$

This is equal to the "harmonic number" function. It follows the rule that natural antidifference in point $x=1$ should have the value of natural integral minus Ramanujan's sum of $1/x$ (which is equal to $\gamma$).

That said I wonder, what is intuitive explanation why the natural integral and natural antidifference of $1/x$ are $\ln|x|+\gamma$ and $\psi(x)+\gamma$ rather than what would be expected more intuitive $\ln x$ (defined as inverse of exponent) and $\psi(x)$ (defined as logarithmic derivative of Gamma function $\psi(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$)

Comment: This reminds me of a nice correspondence I noticed, between $\log(x+1)$ in a continuous context versus $H_n$ in a discrete context; for instance: $$\zeta(2)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{n(n+1)}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(x+1)}{x(x+1)}\,dx.$$